# Convert JSPWiki to XWiki

Tags: text-processing, markdown, document-converter, wiki

## Background

Looking to convert a document written in [JSPWiki format](https://jspwiki-wiki.apache.org/Wiki.jsp?page=TextFormattingRules) to a file written in any format supported by [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).

## Requirements

- Preferably [CommonMark](http://spec.commonmark.org/) or basic HTML output.
- No attachments.
- No predefined server connections (i.e., doesn't attempt to pull/push to/from any Wiki servers).
- Preferably Java, PHP, Lua, or Haskell
- Preferably Windows, but Linux (Cygwin) also works

An example run:

```
wikiconvert --input jspwiki --output commonmark < jspwiki.txt > common.md
```

## Web Page

The HTML generated by JSPWiki does not itself abide by its own rules. For example:

```
!!! Title
```

Becomes:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
```

However, `!!!` is supposed to be `<h1>`, and there are likely other inconsistencies for direct copy/paste conversion from HTML.

## Software

Conversion attempts were made using the following software packages:

- [universal-wiki-converter](https://bitbucket.org/appfusions/universal-wiki-converter) - requires server access (see [exporter](https://migrations.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/UWC/pages/1015846/UWC+Jspwiki+Notes#UWCJspwikiNotes-Exporter))
- [JSPWiki2MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:JSPWiki2MediaWiki) - failed to convert (does not handle image syntax)
- [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org) - does not yet support JSPWiki
- [Marksy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/marksy/glncdocnokppgopgpblpeohhhcjggbnl?hl=en) - does not read JSPWiki formats
- [JSPWiki To XWiki Extension](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/JSPWiki%20To%20XWiki%20Conversion) - incompatible with latest version of XWiki
- [DokuWiki - to - JSPWiki](https://github.com/jrtitus/WikiTransformer) - wrong direction
- [XWiki Filter Streams Converters Application](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Filter%20Application) - does [not support](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Filter+Module#HExistingmodules) JSPWiki
- [JSPWiki Translate Perl](https://github.com/lorrin/JSPWiki-translate-perl) - pandoc does [not support](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/185) reading MoinMoin
- [DokuWiki to JSPWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:jspwiki_convert) - download is [404](https://www.wadds.net.au/Download/jspwiki2dokuwiki-0.3.tgz), but page shows two Perl scripts

## Question

Given a text document written using JSPWiki Markdown format, how can the page be translated into a different format (supported by pandoc or XWiki)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Requirements

Requisite software includes:

- Linux-based operating system (e.g., CentOS, Cygwin)
- [pandoc 2.1](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/) (or newer)
- [JSPWiki2DokuWiki 0.3](https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:jspwiki_convert)
- [dokuwiki2mediawiki.php](https://github.com/tstaerk/mediasyntax/blob/master/tools/dokuwiki2mediawiki.php)

## Installation

Download and install the requisite software as per normal application installation.

### JSPWiki 2 DokuWiki

Install JSPWiki 2 DokuWiki as follows:

1. Download `jspwiki2dokuwiki-0.3.tgz`
2. Extract into `$HOME/bin`

The script is installed.

### DokuWiki 2 MediaWiki

Install DokuWiki 2 MediaWiki as follows:

1. Download `dokuwiki2mediawiki.php` into `$HOME/bin`.

The script is installed.

## Conversion

Convert JSPWiki pages to DokuWiki using a terminal as follows:

1. Edit a JSPWiki page.
2. Copy the text.
3. Open a text editor.
4. Paste the text.
5. Make directories for `$HOME/documents/in` and `$HOME/documents/out`.
6. Save the file (e.g., `$HOME/documents/in/filename.txt`).
7. Change to: `$HOME/bin/jspwiki2dokuwiki-0.3`.
8. Run: `perl migratepages.pl $HOME/documents/in $HOME/documents/out`

The document is converted from JSPWiki to DokuWiki format.

Convert DokuWiki pages to MediaWiki using a terminal as follows:

1. Change to: `$HOME/documents/out`
2. Run: php $HOME/bin/dokuwiki2mediawiki.php filename.txt`.

Convert MediaWiki pages to HTML as follows:

1. Change to: `$HOME/documents/out`
2. Run: `pandoc -f mediawiki -t html filename.txt.mod > filename.html`

The file `filename.html` is created.

The resulting HTML file can be pasted into the WYSIWYG editor used by XWiki and will be converted to XWiki's Markdown format.